# How to change default state for jQuery accordion tab

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using the [jQuery accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default), but the first accordion tab is, by default, already expanded on page load. I tried adding the `aria-selected="false"` to the inline html, and I tried changing/removing this from line 6345 in [jquery-ui.js](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js), but the first tab is still expanded:

```
// make sure at least one header is in the tab order
if ( !this.active.length ) {
    this.headers.eq( 0 ).attr( "tabIndex", 0 );
} else {
    this.active.attr({
        "aria-selected": "true",
        tabIndex: 0
    })
    .next()
        .attr({
            "aria-expanded": "true",
            "aria-hidden": "false"
        });
}
```

Any pointers?

EDIT: new fiddle using the answer below: http://jsfiddle.net/pfeff/WNdRe/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordion jQuery-ui is working with the tabs visibility by changing CSS, but not class of content . Place this in code just after accordion initialization:

```
$("#accordion div.ui-accordion-content").css({"display": "none"});// hide content block
```

UPD:

```
$(...).accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false });
```

UPD 2:

The best way to change original behavior of the original ui element -- create your own plugin or widget :)

http://jsfiddle.net/R8J5p/1/

Now you can use it like `$(...).myAccordion();`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Though in order to get tab #1 to expand, I have to click on tab #2, then on tab #1. Clicking on tab #1 first doesn't expand it.

Comment: Updated the answer. See the fiddle inside.

Comment: So now I feel dumb. I tried recreating your fiddle, and I'm not getting any errors, but it doesn't appear to be applying the accordion at all. Test: http://milespfefferle.com/demo/menutest.html

Comment: Come on! You forgot to include styles in header!